# MIPS Floating point addittion troubleshooting

Tags: mips

So I'm trying to write a program in MIPS assembly code to help me better understand how floating point addition works. I've written a program that gets two inputs from a user, and adds them WITHOUT using any floating point instructions except mtc1 and mfc1 (for input and output). My code has bugs because when I add 1 + 2 I get 2.74804688. I'm still trying to debug the code but can't seem to grasp the problem. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it.

THIS IS MY CODE (excluding the user input...the first floating point value is in $s0, and the second in $s1)

```
#Integer implementation of floating-point addition
 #Initialize variables
 add $s0,$t0,$zero #first integer value
 add $s1,$t1,$zero #second integer value
 add $s2,$zero,$zero #initialize sum variable to 0
 add $t3,$zero,$zero #initialize SUM OF SIGNIFICANDS value to 0

 #get EXPONENT from values
 sll $s5,$s0,1 #getting the exponent value 
srl $s5,$s5,24 #$s5 = first value EXPONENT

 sll $s6,$s1,1 #getting the exponent value
 srl $s6,$s6,24 #$s6 = second value EXPONENT

 #get SIGN from values
 srl $s3,$s0,31 #$s3 = first value SIGN
 srl $s4,$s1,31 #$s4 = second value SIGN

 #get FRACTION from values
 sll $s7,$s0,9 
srl $s7,$s0,9 #$s7 = first value FRACTION
 sll $t8,$s1,9
 srl $t8,$s1,9 #$t8 = second value FRACTION

 #compare the exponents of the two numbers
 compareExp: ###################### 

beq $s5,$s6, addSig 
blt $s5,$s6, shift1 #if first < second, go to shift1
 blt $s6,$s5, shift2 #if second < first, go to shift2
 j compareExp 

shift1: #shift the smaller number to the right
 srl $s7,$s7,1 #shift to the right 1
 addi $s5,$s5,1 
j compareExp

 shift2: #shift the smaller number to the right
 #srl $s0,$s0,1 #shift to the right 1
 #j compareExp
 srl $t8,$t8,1 #shift to the right 1
 addi $s6,$s6,1
 j compareExp

 addSig: 

add $t3,$s7,$t8 #Add the SIGNIFICANDS 

li $v0, 4
 la $a0, sum
 syscall

 li $v0, 1
 move $a0, $t3
 syscall

 j result

 result: 
li $v0, 4
 la $a0, newline
 syscall

 sll $t4,$s3,31 #SIGN
 #FRACTION
 sll $t5,$s6,23 #EXPONENT
 add $t6,$t4,$t5
 add $t6,$t6,$t3

 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, sum2
 syscall

 li $v0, 1
 move $a0, $t6
 syscall

li $v0, 4
 la $a0, newline
 syscall

 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, sum2
 syscall

 li $v0,2
 mtc1 $t6,$f12
 syscall
 jr $31
 # END OF PROGRAM
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using MARS [syscall](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html) 5 to read the inputs, which reads them as integers. You should be reading them as floating point numbers.

You are not including the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) hidden bit when you extract the fractions.

You are not handling the signs of the inputs correctly.

There's a lot more, but that's enough for now.